# How to refresh a cached Drupal page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-cache

Is it possible to let Drupal refresh one particular cached page?

Currently, one page of our site shows some dynamic table data by [Table Wizard](http://drupal.org/project/tw). After some update in MySQL table, the page does not fresh.

I assume it's due to the site caching is on (Caching mode is set to: Normal). For anonymous users, the page refresh sort of 60 minutes later.

Instead of clearing the whole site's cache, is there a way to let Drupal refresh only one page? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to "let Drupal refresh one particular" page is to just keep it out of the cache.

The [cacheexclude](http://drupal.org/project/cacheexclude) module is designed for this. Just tell it the page(s) you want kept out of cache.

If you don't want to install another module, you can override hook_init():

```
mymodule_init() {
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias(request_uri());
  if ($path == "<do not cache path>") {
    $GLOBALS['conf']['cache'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Will this work inside hook_init if the page is already in cache? I think hook_init is never invoked if page is already in cache. If I'm correct about that `hook_boot` may be a better place to do this if serving from cache has to be disabled only for some requests based on some logical condition.